# Edits on Map show up on plunkr but not on fresh local angular/cli-generated project

Tags: angular

When you call `set` on a Map or WeakMap, Angular does not pick up the change **unless you're on plnkr**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="onClick()">click</button>
      {{ map | json }}
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`

  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  map = new Map();

  onClick () {
    this.map.set({'a':Math.random()}, {[Math.random()]: {'a':Math.random()}})
    console.log(this.map);
  }
}
```

This very simple piece of code **will** update as expected in Plunkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/xbn82sr8KK0oe4WjCX1m?p=preview

But locally, in a project freshly created via @angular/cli, it will not work
The console log shows the map is being set to, but the screen only ever renders an empty array.

Adding a ChangeDetectorRef and `detectChanges` or `markForCheck` does nothing.

Repo here: 
https://github.com/cheapsteak/ng-debug-map/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution...
In `polyfills.ts`, add

```
import 'core-js/shim';
```

towards the top of the file